# How do I enforce settings for an extension in chrome using mac?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I'd like to enforce settings for an extension called uBlacklist. I want to make sure that every instance of Chrome on my computer has the same settings.

I'd like to edit it's settings, specifically adding this value to the blocklist `*://acme.com/*` and making sure the extension is on for regular browsing and in cognito browsing.

It appears that I can set Chrome-level settings for the extensions with the [ExtensionSettings](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3/extension-settings-full) policy, but I don't see options for this extension-specific settings.

Can I either set the settings with the policies file or block the extension settings url after I've set the settings (`chrome-extension://pncfbmialoiaghdehhbnbhkkgmjanfhe/options.html`) along with preventing disabling in in cognito?

Comment: In Windows, extensions are stored inside the Chrome profile, where extensions are contained in folders within the Default directory. By copying the entire folder for an extension, you will also be copying its settings. For the Mac, see the post [Where to find extensions installed folder for Google Chrome on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17377337/where-to-find-extensions-installed-folder-for-google-chrome-on-mac). Does that help?

Comment: Interesting. My concern is that even if I start with the right settings for the extension, the user on the computer can go in and change the settings. I'd like to enforce a prescriptive list.

Comment: You could perhaps enforce this by not giving the user-account modify permissions on the extension's folder.

Comment: Oh interesting, and that will override changing the settings within the Chrome browser

Comment: Did you use my above advice?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but I'm confident that it'll work. Can you please post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome extensions are stored inside the Chrome profile, inside the `Default` folder
and then inside the `Extensions` sub-folder, where each extension has its own
sub-folder.
One may find the profile folder by entering in the Chrome address-bar
`chrome://version` and looking for "Profile Path".

For the Mac, see also  the post
[Where to find extensions installed folder for Google Chrome on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17377337/where-to-find-extensions-installed-folder-for-google-chrome-on-mac).

Copying the entire folder of an extension, means that you will also be copying
its settings.

If you wish to prevent a non-admin user from modifying an extension's settings,
you may enforce this by not giving the user's account Modify permissions
on the extension's folder.

Comment: Do you have an option that supports doing this in Firefox?